# session value does not get renewed

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a function in the controller of my codeigniter project in which based on what has been posted to it, the session value is updated!

In Controller:

```
function inquire_cdrcounts(){
    $this->session->unset_userdata('r_type');
    if($this->input->post('criteria')=="m"){
        $this->session->set_userdata('r_type','Months');
    }
    if($this->input->post('criteria')=="d"){
        $this->session->set_userdata('r_type','Days');
    }
....
....
}
```

In View:

```
if($this->session->userdata('r_type','Days'))
    echo substr($key->date_time,8,2);
elseif($this->session->userdata('r_type','Months'))
    echo substr($key->date_time,5,2);
```

And it prints the result of both conditions!
How come the both conditions are true??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check like this,

```
if($this->session->userdata('r_type') == 'Days')
    echo substr($key->date_time,8,2);
elseif($this->session->userdata('r_type') == 'Months')
    echo substr($key->date_time,5,2);
```